# Internal server error when downloading files from survey [Limesurvey]

Tags: iis, sql-server-2012, internal-server-error, limesurvey

I can not understand what is happening. The situation is like this: I upload a file when answering to question, which is "File Upload" type in survey. Then I try to download files from that response and everything is ok, but after 2-3 hours - I can't download it as zip file and I get this:

"Internal Server Error

Column name must be either a string or an array.

An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact the webmaster to report this problem.

Thank you."

However, downloading file(-s) by pushing on its title (like text.txt) is ok. Could someone help me with this? Applications/programs, used by LimeSurvey: MS SQL Server 2012, PHP v5.3, IIS web server.

P.S. Files exist in survey's directory on server.

Answer (score 0):

after 2-3 hours => maybe just some session issue : are you connected to LimeSurvey admin

And need to know your LimeSurvey version and build number

Comment: Yes, I am connected as admin. But other user, who has superadmin permissions, has the same issue. LimeSurvey version 2.05+, Build 140811. It could be session issue, but how should I fix it? Because if after few hours I can't download files as zip file from survey, I can't edit/delete neither of responses.

Comment: Your survey use lt language ? Strange , there are no lt language in LimeSurvey.

Comment: Yes, it is Lithuanian. Well, I can choose lithuanian when logging on.

Comment: Column name must be either a string or an array. : maybe a bug in LimeSurvey. MySQL accept column name staring by number. And column name are 1234X454X6565 in LimeSurvey. Then bug need to be reported : https://www.limesurvey.org/en/community-services/bug-tracker

Comment: Can you give me the link or the number of the bug report ? I'm not the MSSQL specialist but i like to see.

Comment: This one : http://bugs.limesurvey.org/view.php?id=9331 ? If yes, it's better if you leave the SQL error for Carsten ....